# Интеграция фейсбук сдк где взять ключи

Tags: android, facebooksdk

где прописать эту строку `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` для получения ключей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через командную строку:
Жмем win+R, набираем cmd, enter.
`cd c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin`
У меня в таком пути. Далее уже вызываем вашу команду с вашим путем и алиасом до дебажного ключа.

Comment: Возможно `cd c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin` ? нужно вводить именно так! У меня вышло. Но запрашивает пароль. Странно этого не написали на фейсбуке.

Comment: @Devel0 По умолчанию пароль просто android